# Qt Creator не отображает отладочную информацию от GDB

Tags: linux, qt, centos, gdb

- Centos 7
- gcc 7.3.1
- gdb 8.0.1-36.el7
- cmake3 3.11.2
- python 2.7.5

(Использую devtoolset-7)
Qt установлен отдельно из `qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.11.0.run`.

Отладчик останавливается на точках останова, продолжает по <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> и т.д., но не показывает отладочную информацию: значения переменных, стек вызовов, текущую выполняемую строку и т.д..

Как это исправить?

[image: 0_1529045998034_Снимок экрана от 2018-06-15 09-51-28.png]

Comment: Если щёлкать мышкой в пустых полях, то ширина столбцов меняется, так-же можно вызвать контекстное меню по правой кнопке мыши. Значит на самом деле строки с именами переменных, их значениями и т. д. присутствуют, но не отрисовываются. Проблема со шрифтами? или с чем-то ещё?

Comment: При наведении указателя мыши на переменную он отображает её значение в всплывающем окне. Пробовал менять шрифты. Заменил Qt Creator c 4.6.1 на 4.6.2. Результат тот-же.

Comment: Попробуйте сменить тему `Creator` на темную. Может, какая-то игра с инверсией цветов.

Comment: При смене темы, результат тот-же. Вывод конца журнала отладки:
&"python theDumper.fetchStack({"limit":20,"nativemixed":0,"token":21})\n"
&"Traceback (most recent call last):\n"
&" File "<string>", line 1, in <module>\n"
&" File "/opt/Qt5.11.0/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/debugger/gdbbridge.py", line 1304, in fetchStack\n"
&" objfile = fromNativePath(symtab.objfile.filename)\n"
&"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 34-39: ordinal not in range(128)\n"
&"Error while executing Python code.\n"
21^error,msg="Error while executing Python code."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в наличии каталога с русскими буквами в пути к проекту. Не думал, что для Linux это тоже актуально.